# Pass function via directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I invoke a function via an directive attribute **without** isolated scope. I know that it possible with `$parse` and `link`.

For example:

```
<my-directive on-start="foo(query)> </my-directive>
```

And I want to invoke the function in the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With scope.$eval:

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$eval(attrs.onStart);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the directive I have an input text and a button, I want that the onStart fund will start before the function of the button clicked (and not when click the element).

Comment: Then just take the `scope.$eval` out of the `element.on` block. It will run immediately as the directive is evaluated.